# Surface Tension On The Surfaces which are not exposed to Environment

Tags: surface-tension

In the picture Below, I was asked to Calculate the force due to **surface tension** on the left side of the water about an imaginary square ABCD by the right side of water. ($T$ = surface Tenson)

[image]

One has considered Surface Tenson along the line *AB*, which is equal to
$F_{ab} = 2RT$

I think there should be another surface tension forces that acts about the whole perimeter of square *ABCD*, But it is not considered.
If considered , net force will be $$F_(net) = 2(2RT) + 2(hT)$$
Does surface tension act only where it is exposed to the environment?
If Yes then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface tension is a property of the two surfaces that are in contact. It is numerically equal to the interfacial energy per unit area between the two surfaces. See [Reason for nature of surface tension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/751966/reason-for-nature-of-surface-tension) for more on this.

So in this case we have a liquid-air tension, $T_{\ell a}$, where the liquid and the air are in contact, but also a liquid-solid tension, $T_{\ell s}$, where the liquid and the solid walls of the container are in contact.

So you are basically correct, but the total force would be:

$$ F = 2RT_{\ell a} + (h + 2R + h)T_{\ell s} $$